# How to change inf values in numpy array for the previous non inf value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, inf

I have a numpy array that may contain inf values.

The numpy array is a 1D vector of numbers.

Is there a way to change the inf values of the array for the previous value of the array (which is not inf)?

So if the 1000th index of the array is an inf it should replace it by the 999th index which is not inf.

Heres an example of what I want

```py
vals = np.random.random(10000)
vals[vals<0.1] = np.inf

indexes = np.asarray(vals==np.inf).nonzero()

for i in indexes:
    vals[i] = vals[i-1]

if np.isinf(vals).any():
    print("It doesnt work")
else:
    print("It works")
```

Comment: what do you mean by the previous value of the array , is it elements of any array ?

Comment: Ive edited the question to make it more clear. Does that answer the question?

Comment: You can do like this `my_arr[1000] = my_arr[999] `

Comment: A general version is what im looking for.

Comment: How about adding an example that we can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you not use the simplest way?

```
for i in range (0,len(a)):
    if a[i]==inf: a[i]=a[i-1]
```

I have never work with inf. maybe you the type of it is str and so you should write a[i]=='inf'

Comment: inf should be np.inf. Also is there a better way? My arrays are very big.

Answer (score 1):

```
def pandas_fill(arr):
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
    df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1, inplace=True)
    out = df.as_matrix()
    return out

def numpy_fill(arr):
    mask = np.isnan(arr)
    idx = np.where(~mask,np.arange(mask.shape[1]),0)
    np.maximum.accumulate(idx,axis=1, out=idx)
    out = arr[np.arange(idx.shape[0])[:,None], idx]
    return out
```

`inf` and `-inf` will be loaded as `nan`. So, this should be handled with that.

Try out this updated one.

```
import numpy as np

Data = np.array([np.nan,1.3,np.nan,1.4,np.nan,np.nan])

nansIndx = np.where(np.isnan(Data))[0]
isanIndx = np.where(~np.isnan(Data))[0]
for nan in nansIndx:
    replacementCandidates = np.where(isanIndx>nan)[0]
    if replacementCandidates.size != 0:
        replacement = Data[isanIndx[replacementCandidates[0]]]
    else:
        replacement = Data[isanIndx[np.where(isanIndx<nan)[0][-1]]]
    Data[nan] = replacement
print(Data)
```

Comment: can you post the error please. I hope you have imported pandas or numpy whichever you are using

Comment: for the pandas: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'.

Comment: for the numpy: IndexError: tuple index out of range. At the line idx = np.where(~mask,np.arange(mask.shape[1]),0)

Comment: I dont know if it matters but my array has a len of 1.000.000

Comment: try out the updated script that i have posted

Comment: What if there are multiple inf's in a row? Do you want the closest previous value that isn't inf? If the first element is inf, what should it be?

Comment: Yes, I want the closest previous thats not inf. The first element shouldnt be an inf. This solution works fine i think. But ive repplaced the isnan for isinf